# Asp.Net build display all errors in error window

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, publish

Consider Asp.net Website (not web app) with .Net 4.5 framework.
With multiple cs / aspx / ascx files in many different folders outside App_Code folder.
App_Code folder compiles perfectly. Able to map with IIS and browse few pages.
But many files present outside the App_Code folder contains errors, during build / rebuild, it shows only one error at a time.  Once that error is fixed, during next build, again error is thrown in some other in file outside App_Code folder.
How to display all the errors?
I mean, like, when there are errors in multiple C# files present in App_Code folder, all the errors get displayed in Error window. Same thing how to configure for files present outside App_Code, so that error finding will be faster?

Comment: the error you are facing might be linked with other classes. Have patience, fix them. It's not necessary to fire all error for VS. i also ran in to this type of problem and resolved it one after another sometimes.